# Is it possible to use KeyBindings in JFrame & Canvas?

Tags: java, swing, input, keyboard-shortcuts, jcomponent

I've been have difficulty with `KeyListener` (not detecting keys) and I'm trying to switch over to KeyBindings but `JFrame` doesn't extend `JComponent` which is needed for the getInputMap() function. Any ideas?

Comment: Trying using a custom `contentPane` (something like a `JPanel`) and then add the `Canvas` onto it

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'll try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a surrogate `JComponent` instead.  For example, set the frame's `contentPane` to be a `JPanel` and use it to register the key bindings.

This is a very basic example, which uses a `JPanel` as the `contentPane` and adds a `Canvas` to it.  The key bindings are then registered through the `JPanel` on behalf of the `Canvas` which is actually used to respond to them.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setContentPane(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Surface surface;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            surface = new Surface();

            InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), "Pressed.left");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), "Release.left");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), "Pressed.right");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), "Release.right");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), "Pressed.up");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, true), "Release.up");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, false), "Pressed.down");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, true), "Release.down");

            actionMap.put("Pressed.left", surface.getLeftPressAction());
            actionMap.put("Release.left", surface.getLeftReleaseAction());
            actionMap.put("Pressed.right", surface.getRightPressAction());
            actionMap.put("Release.right", surface.getRightReleaseAction());
            actionMap.put("Pressed.up", surface.getUpPressAction());
            actionMap.put("Release.up", surface.getUpReleaseAction());
            actionMap.put("Pressed.down", surface.getDownPressAction());
            actionMap.put("Release.down", surface.getDownReleaseAction());

            add(surface);
        }

    }

    public class Surface extends Canvas {

        private String displayText = "...";

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g); 
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(displayText)) / 2;
            int y = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
            g2d.drawString(displayText, x, y);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        public Action getLeftPressAction() {
            return new TextAction("Left");
        }

        public Action getLeftReleaseAction() {
            return new ClearAction();
        }

        public Action getRightPressAction() {
            return new TextAction("Right");
        }

        public Action getRightReleaseAction() {
            return new ClearAction();
        }

        public Action getUpPressAction() {
            return new TextAction("Up");
        }

        public Action getUpReleaseAction() {
            return new ClearAction();
        }

        public Action getDownPressAction() {
            return new TextAction("Down");
        }

        public Action getDownReleaseAction() {
            return new ClearAction();
        }

        public class TextAction extends AbstractAction {
            private String text;

            public TextAction(String text) {
                this.text = text;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                displayText = text;
                repaint();
            }

        }

        public class ClearAction extends AbstractAction {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                displayText = "...";
                repaint();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

This example only override's the `Canvas`s `paint` method, but the concept should still work for implementations using `BufferStrategy`