# Java not detecting Keyboard Input (letters)

Tags: java, macos, swing, keyboard, key-bindings

I'm making a 2d game engine and trying to improve the input system. When I try to use the WASD keys, the `KeyListener` sometimes won't detect the key being pressed but it still detects it being released. I tried using `KeyBindings` instead but I get the same problem. Anyone know what's going on?

(maybe it has something to do with my IDE(netbeans), mac, or java?)

edit: here's someone else's code that has the same problem

```
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setContentPane(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Surface surface;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            surface = new Surface();

            InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
System.out.println("yo");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), "Pressed.left");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), "Release.left");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), "Pressed.right");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), "Release.right");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), "Pressed.up");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, true), "Release.up");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, false), "Pressed.down");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, true), "Release.down");

            actionMap.put("Pressed.left", surface.getLeftPressAction());
            actionMap.put("Release.left", surface.getLeftReleaseAction());
            actionMap.put("Pressed.right", surface.getRightPressAction());
            actionMap.put("Release.right", surface.getRightReleaseAction());
            actionMap.put("Pressed.up", surface.getUpPressAction());
            actionMap.put("Release.up", surface.getUpReleaseAction());
            actionMap.put("Pressed.down", surface.getDownPressAction());
            actionMap.put("Release.down", surface.getDownReleaseAction());

            add(surface);
        }

    }

    public class Surface extends Canvas {

        private String displayText = "...";

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g); 
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(displayText)) / 2;
            int y = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
            g2d.drawString(displayText, x, y);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        public Action getLeftPressAction() {
            return new TextAction("Left");
        }

        public Action getLeftReleaseAction() {
            return new ClearAction();
        }

        public Action getRightPressAction() {
            return new TextAction("Right");
        }

        public Action getRightReleaseAction() {
            return new ClearAction();
        }

        public Action getUpPressAction() {
            return new TextAction("Up");
        }

        public Action getUpReleaseAction() {
            return new ClearAction();
        }

        public Action getDownPressAction() {
            return new TextAction("Down");
        }

        public Action getDownReleaseAction() {
            return new ClearAction();
        }

        public class TextAction extends AbstractAction {
            private String text;

            public TextAction(String text) {
                this.text = text;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                displayText = text;
                repaint();
            }

        }

        public class ClearAction extends AbstractAction {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                displayText = "...";
                repaint();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: "Please help me debug code that I'm not showing" -- **very** hard to do. Please fix; please create and post your valid [mcve].

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thats not what i'm asking...

Comment: Your code is not behaving as expected -- that's a bug in *your* code, and you're asking why, and that requires appropriate code, and so yes it *is* in fact what you're asking.

Comment: Please have another look at the [mcve] link since if your code fulfills the protocol, we'll have a much easier time helping to find a solution. Good luck.

Comment: Take 10-20 minutes to write an MCVE (a *new* program). If the bug is in your MCVE, then post it and we can help. If the bug is not in your MCVE, then you need to figure out what the difference between the two programs is. Either you'll find the bug, or you'll have a program you can post that doesn't take us too long to analyze.

Comment: Hmmm, [that looks familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49329348/is-it-possible-to-use-keybindings-in-jframe-canvas) which works fine on my Mac

Comment: *"here's someone else's code that has the same problem"* - Seriously? *"My code has a problem, here's someone elses"* ??? By the way - I've copied and pasted that code and it still works just fine

Comment: @MadProgrammer really? i guess it's my IDE or something...

Comment: @IspellColourWithAU No idea, but the pasted code works fine for me

Comment: Why do you have a JPanel and a Canvas? Get rid of the Canvas and do the custom painting on the JPanel, by overriding paintComponent() not paint(), where you have all the bindings. Don't use an AWT component in a Swing application.

Comment: This isn’t the cause of your problem, but… if you create a Graphics with `g.create()`, make sure you call dispose() on it when you’re done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried using the jar file in a windows 10 and it worked perfectly... It may have something to do with my operating system or my version of java.